# Prove $ \sum\nolimits_{n=1}^{ \infty } u_n(x)$ converges uniformly at $[0,1]$, when $u_n(x) = (-1)^n*(1-x)*x^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I can't understand how to prove that
$ \sum\nolimits_{n=1}^{ \infty } u_n(x)$ converges uniformly at $[0,1]$, when $u_n(x) = (-1)^n*(1-x)*x^n$.

I tried using Weierstrass M-test - bounding those functions with a converging series $ \sum M_n$, which will result in $ |u_n(x)| \leq \sum M_n$. But after 1 and 1/2 hours I couldn't find the right usage here.

I'm aware of the other question linked to that, but it doesn't answer exactly the same thing.

Would much appreciate help. Thank you!

Comment: You already posted [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3826301/148510) an hour ago. Please do not double post.

Comment: @RRL Someone deleted my question because it linked it to an old question, which is not really related

Comment: The question was **not** deleted.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3816795/148510) may help you.